# "Close" message on desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have been having this message on my screen for over a week now. It is on top of every app and never goes away, even after a restart.
I have 3 screens and no new software has been installed.
It's very annoying, specially on full screen apps or watching a video. Anyone has an idea of how to remove it?

[image: example image]

[image: 2 example]

Comment: I can't see the image, please upload it in  your post, and give some more information if available about such program

Comment: @fernando.reyes I uploaded a second image. It's on the desktop, no other program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a tooltip of some program that hangs in there unidentified, and will disappear when the program is closed.

That tooltip is similar to the one on this image:
[image: tooltip]
that is the Close tooltip from a toolbar in Visual Studio.

You can try to identify it downloading [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), and once you open the program click the Find Window's Process button [image: find]
on the toolbar, and drag it to the [Close] tooltip you want to identify.

Luckily it will send you to the program that opened it and you can put an end to it.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, I was able to identify the program with the SysInternals Process Explorer. It was a Genius Camera capturing image software that was hanging right after boot.